# automatic ssh connection with use the passphrase key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I use the key pair with passphrase for the host connection on ssh.
Is it possible to specify this passpharase in ssh_config on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in `ssh_config` file, but try with `ssh-agent` command.

Comment: Indeed - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#SSH_agents.
Thank you!